# Javascript - Regular expressions Not consistent match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting crazy with this problem, I try to extract "Latin" sentences from the following string (shorter than the original) :

```
My Name is Yoann

ホームインサイト最新のインサイト運用チームからの最新のマーケ
ットアップデート、運用アップデートマーケットアップデート市場環境情報に関す
るレポート投資アップデート投資環境情報レポート及び出版物運用戦略運用戦略
ファーストステート・スチュワートアジア・パシフィック、グローバル・エマージング・マーケット、ワールドワイド株式

Hello World
```

Here is the regular expression :

```
...
//text=My Name is Yoann...
pattern = new RegExp("([A-Za-z]+[\s]?[A-Za-z])+", "g");
results= text.match(pattern);
```

When I run that, I get :

```
//results[0]="My"
//results[1]="Name"
//results[2]="is"
//results[3]="Yoann"
//...
```

The words are splitted on "space". When I try on the http://regexlib.com (JS client engine) tester or http://regexpal.com, the results are :

```
//results[0]="My Name is Yoann"
//results[1]="Hello World"
```

So I don't understand what i do wrong in my code but I don't get the same results.

Thanks for your help.

Yoann

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> "foo bar".match(new RegExp("[a-z]\s[a-z]"))
null
> "foo bar".match(new RegExp("[a-z]\\s[a-z]"))
["o b"]
```

When using the RegExp constructor, double your slashes. Better yet, use regex literals, e.g.

```
/[A-Z][A-Z\s]*[A-Z]|[A-Z]/gi
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4PdJh/1

Comment: regex literal! Thanks a lot. I struggled hours!